# DNS address could not be found. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: php, wampserver

i install wampserver3...but the port number 80 was using by another program, so i has change the port number from 80 to 8383 ...now server getting started but i am unable to find my project. it gives ->
This site can’t be reached
dailydiary’s server DNS address could not be found.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
please help me.

Comment: Port numbers have NOTHING to do with dns. And DNS problems are not programming-releated, so... off-topic.

Comment: Show the url you are entering into the browser

Comment: ya its working......thank u RiggsFolly